# $ M_{G} $ is the core of $ M $ in $ G $. Let $ M_{G} = 1 $. Why $ M $ is a complement for $ N $ in $ G $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ M $ maximal subgroup of solvable group $ G $, and assume that $ G = MC $ for some cyclic subgroup $ C $. Let $ N $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $, then $ N $ is an elementary abelian $ p $-subgroup. $ M_{G} $ is the core of $ M $ in $ G $. Let $ M_{G} = 1 $. Why $ M $ is a complement for $ N $ in $ G $?

Comment: Hint: try looking at $M \cap N$.

Comment: @Leppala I try but didn't get result. I try show $ M \cap N = 1 $ and $ G = MN $ but didn't get result.

Comment: Ok, another hint: Can you show that $M \cap N$ is normal in $M$? Do you see how that would help?

Comment: @Leppala yes , $ M \cap N \lhd M $, since $ N \lhd G $ and $ M \leq G $. true ?

Comment: Can you conclude that then $M \cap N$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: No, If $ M \cap N \lhd G $ then $ M \cap N = 1 $ since $ M_{G} = 1 $.

Comment: That's what you're trying to show here!

Comment: @Leppala But how? I don't conclude $ M \cap N \lhd G $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M_G$ is trivial, we know that $N \not \leq M$. As $M$ is maximal in $G$, it follows that $G = MN$.

Let $m \in M$ and $x \in M \cap N$. Then $m^{-1}xm \in M \cap N$, since $N \unlhd G$. Hence $M \cap N \unlhd M$. As $N$ is abelian, also $M \cap N \unlhd N$. Thus $M \cap N \unlhd MN = G$.

Now $M \cap N \unlhd G$, but as $M_G$ is trivial, we conclude that $M \cap N = 1$. Thus $M$ is a complement to $N$.